# Horizontal Bar chart with vertical line is possible or not in D3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to generate a Barchart in NVD3 with a vertical line. 
but it is not possible please help and adivice some suggestions

Horizontal Bar chart with vertical line is possible or not in D3

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
holder.append("line")          // attach a line
.style("stroke", "black")     // colour the line
.attr("x1", 100)     // x position of the first end of the line
.attr("y1", 50)      // y position of the first end of the line
.attr("x2", 300)     // x position of the second end of the line
.attr("y2", 150);    // y position of the second end of the line
```